# Passing parameters to remote SSRS report from ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses SSRS for reporting (using a web form and report viewer). I would like to pass two parameters dynamically to the remote report. My current implementation stores the parameters in session, which works fine on VS Development Server, but the variable is null on IIS, upon retrieval in the web form.

Here is the controller method that calls the view

```
    public ActionResult ShowReport(string id)
    {
        var reportParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        reportParameters.Add("Param1", id);
        reportParameters.Add("Param2", "user1");
        Session["reportParameters"] = reportParameters;

        return View("ReportName");
    }
```

And here is how I attempt to retrieve the parameters from the web form

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reportParameters = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["reportParameters"];

        foreach (var item in reportParameters)
        {
            ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter(item.Key, item.Value);
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rp);
        }
    }
```

Anyone know why Session["reportParameters"] is null?
Or is there some other way of passing these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it too:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {

                var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                string reportPath= Request.QueryString["LocalReport"];
                string parametersTemp = Request.QueryString["ParametersReport"];
                List<ReportParameter> parameters = null;

                if (parametrosTemp != "")
                {
                    parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
                                            <List<ReportParameter>>(parametrosTemp);
                }

                GenerateReport(reportPath, parameters );
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                statusReport.Value = ex.Message;
            }

        }
     }



    private void GenerateReport(string reportPath, List<ReportParameter> reportParameters)
    {

        reportCurrent.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ServerReport serverReport = reportCurrent.ServerReport;

        serverReport.ReportServerUrl =
            new Uri(AppSettings.URLReportServer);
            serverReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
        serverReport.Refresh();

        if (reportParameters != null)
        {
          reportCurrent.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that `Session["reportParameters"]` is null or is it that you don't get any parameters added to your report? Because your code, as it stands, won't add parameters to your report even if you pass them across properly and so the report parameters will be null.

[`SetParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252178%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) takes `IEnumerable<ReportParameter>` (usually a `List`), not a `ReportParameter`object. Your code should look more like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var reportParameters = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["reportParameters"];
    List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();

    foreach (var item in reportParameters)
    {
        parameters.Add(new ReportParameter(item.Key, item.Value););
    } 
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
}
```